# Why are there hexadecimal numbers included in my view results from CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

Why are there hexadecimal numbers included in my view results from CouchDB? How can I get rid of them?

```
7f
{"total_rows":108,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"5c718dbd01bc0cde8152e08ed6003405","key":"2013-03-19T22:43:27.2683661Z","value":0}
5b
,

...

{"id":"5c718dbd01bc0cde8152e08ed6037404","key":"2013-03-19T23:07:35.5972058Z","value":0}
5b
,
{"id":"5c718dbd01bc0cde8152e08ed60376e5","key":"2013-03-19T23:07:35.6062063Z","value":0}
4

]}
1

0
```

---

**TL;DR**

I am new to CouchDB, and are investigating its use as a database for an event log. I have created a simple map function to view the event log by date:

```
function(doc)
{
    if (doc.DateTime)
    {
        emit(doc.DateTime, doc);
    }
}
```

When I use Fiddler to test this view with the following request:

```
GET http://localhost:5984/stuff/_design/eventlog/_view/datetime

Host: localhost:5984
User-Agent: Fiddler
```

The results returned included hexadecimal numbers that aren't a part of the JSON structure. Hence the JSON returned is invalid. Why are these hexadecimal numbers included in the results, and how can I get rid of them?

I am using Windows (x86) CouchDB version 1.2.1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To get a pure JSON result you must include the `Accept: application/json` header in your HTTP request.

If you omit the the `Accept` header CouchDB will return results in a manner that is more suitable for displaying nicely in web browsers. The results will be in a JSON format, but with a  `text/plain` content-type.

See [Apache CouchDB 1.3 Manual Section 2.2.1. Request Headers](http://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api-basics.html#http-headers).

The hexadecimal numbers are a result of [Chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).

Answer (score 2):

The weird hex numbers are used for so-called chuncked transfer-encoding. This is a way for HTTP responses to become available in a streaming format instead of the client having to wait for entire response to be ready. The hex numbers denote the length for the next chunk.

I think the use of chunking is independent of the request's Accept values, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes! The response has the `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header which explains the numbers. Thanks so much. I looked all over to for an explanation.

Comment: @djc Do not ask people to upvote or accept your answer. They will if they want, and should not be pressured into it.